# Problemas con declaracion preparada (Prepared Statement) en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Mi problema es el siguiente: He estado haciendo una tabla dinamica donde se agreguen datos en una tabla y se guarden en la base de datos. Estoy usando javascript en html para mandar llamar una funcion en un archivo javascript usando ajax para hacer una peticion POST. De ahi todo bien pero cuando se va a al archivo PHP con el query de insertar a la tabla en la base de datos, me sucede un error. Ya no se que mas moverle porque al parecer todo esta en orden. Muchas gracias!

Este es el HTML

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalNuevolLabel">Agregar Nuevo Registro</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label>Nombre de curso</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre_curso_agregar" class="form-control input-group-sm">

                        <label>Periodo</label>
                        <input type="text" id="periodo_agregar" class="form-control input-group-sm">

                        <label>Horas de capacitacion</label>
                        <input type="text" id="horas_capacitacion_agregar" class="form-control input-group-sm">

                        <label>Numero de participantes base</label>
                        <input type="text" id="numero_participantes_base_agregar" class="form-control input-group-sm">

                        <label>Numero de participantes Honorarios/Itinerarios</label>
                        <input type="text" id="numero_participantes_honorarios_agregar" class="form-control input-group-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_agregar_curso_actual">Guardar nuevo registro</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tablaRegistroCurso').load('componentes/TablaRegistroCurso.php');

    });


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_agregar_curso_actual').click(function () {
            nombre_curso = $('#nombre_curso_agregar').val();
            periodo = $('#periodo_agregar').val();
            horas_capacitacion = $('#horas_capacitacion_agregar').val();
            numero_participantes_base = $('#numero_participantes_base_agregar').val();
            numero_participantes_honorarios = $('#numero_participantes_honorarios_agregar').val();
            agregarDatos(nombre_curso,periodo,horas_capacitacion,numero_participantes_base,
                                  numero_participantes_honorarios);
        })

    });

</script>
```

El codigo javascript

```
function agregarDatos(nombre_curso,periodo,horas_capacitacion,numero_participantes_base,
                      numero_participantes_honorarios) {
    cadena = "nombre_curso=" + nombre_curso +
        "&periodo=" + periodo +
        "&horas_capacitacion=" + horas_capacitacion +
        "&numero_participantes_base" + numero_participantes_base +
        "&numero_participantes_honorarios" + numero_participantes_honorarios;

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"php/agregarDatos.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r) {
            if(r==1){
                $('#tablaRegistroCurso').load('componentes/TablaRegistroCurso.php');
                alertify.success("Agregado con exito: ");
            }
            else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servidor");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Y el codigo PHP

```php
<?php


    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion = conexion();

    $nombre_curso=$_POST['nombre_curso'];
    $periodo=$_POST['periodo'];
    $horas_capacitacion=$_POST['horas_capacitacion'];
    $numero_participantes_base=$_POST['numero_participantes_base'];
    $numero_participantes_honorarios=$_POST['numero_participantes_honorarios'];

    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("insert into cursos_formacion_docente_actualizacion_profesional (nombre_curso,
                                        periodo,horas_capacitacion,numero_participantes_base,numero_participantes_honorarios)
                                        values (?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssiii",$nombre_curso,$periodo, $horas_capacitacion,
                                        $numero_participantes_base,$numero_participantes_honorarios);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega el error que obtienes

Comment: lo unico que veo es que en el javascript en la variable cadena en los ultimos 2, falta el "=", si no compartes cual es el error, más no te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Hay varias cosas: 1º. En Ajax es mejor pasar un objeto en las peticiones del tipo POST, por lo tanto, construye `cadena` de este modo: `var cadena = {nombre_curso: nombre_curso, periodo: periodo, horas_capacitacion: horas_capacitacion, numero_participantes_base: numero_participantes_base, numero_participantes_honorarios: numero_participantes_honorarios};` es mucho más claro y menos propenso a errores. Prueba así y dinos qué pasa y si da error di qué error es. Como recomendación evita usar nombres de variables tan largos, eso produce un código enorme, difícil de analizar.

Comment: 2º. No estás respondiendo nada desde el servidor. Debes verificar si todo está bien y emitir un `echo 1;` dado que luego en Ajax haces esto: `if(r==1){` pero `r` no tendrá nada, porque nada respondiste desde el servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias A. Cedano!!, efectivamente era eso que no respondía nada el servidor y se arreglo cuando hice echo en cuanto se ejecutara la query. Saludos!!